# Get every combination from a list using python including duplicate

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am facing a problem to get all the combinations.
For example I want to get the combination of ['A','B','C'].
I want this answers:
AAA
AAB
AAC
ABA
ABB
ABC
ACA
ACB
ACC
.......... CCA CCB CCC.
So help me to get this python. Don't use 3 nested for loop.

Comment: Take a look at the [itertools library of Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Comment: Specifically, `itertools.product(items,repeat=3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want permutation with repetition.

```
arr = ["A", "B", "C"]

def perm(ans, prev, arr, k):
    if len(prev) == k:
        ans.append(prev)
        return
    
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        perm(ans, prev + [arr[i]], arr, k)
        
ans = []
k = 3
perm(ans, [], arr, k)
for x in ans:
    print(x)
```